# Error in JavaScript return code?

Tags: javascript

Here is the javascript code: 
There is an error in code where nightSurcharges is added to total cost even if pickUptime is less than 20.

```
function TaxiFare() {

    var baseFare = 2;
    var costPerMile = 0.50;
    var nightSurcharge = 0.50; // 8pm to 6am, every night //its flat 0.50 and not per mile
    var milesTravelled = Number(document.getElementById("miles").value) || 0;
    if ((milesTravelled < 1) || (milesTravelled > 200)) {
        alert("You must enter 1 - 200 miles");
        document.getElementById("miles").focus();
        return false;
    }

    var pickupTime = Number(document.getElementById("putime").value) || 0;
    if ((pickupTime == "") || (pickupTime < 0) || (pickupTime > 23)) {
        alert("The time must be 0-23 hours");
        document.getElementById("putime").focus();
        return false;
    }

    var cost = baseFare + (costPerMile * milesTravelled);

    // add the nightSurcharge to the cost if it is after
    // 8pm or before 6am
    if (pickupTime >= 20 || pickupTime < 6) {
        cost += nightSurcharge;
    }
    alert("Your taxi fare is $" + cost.toFixed(2));
}
```

I want nightSurcharge to be added only when pickupTime is >=20, but that's not working right now.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? It sounds like you're just posting the problem and expecting someone else to fix it.

Comment: `if (pickupTime >= 20 || pickupTime < 6) {
    cost += nightSurcharge;
}` "I want nightSurcharge to be added only when pickupTime is >=20" wait a sec r u trying to homework me

Comment: what is the exact error, and wich numbers did you use to produce this error?

Comment: The comment explains the code: add the night surcharge if it's after 2000 or before 0600. That seems reasonable. Are you saying that the surcharge should not apply after midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems obvious to me.

```
if (pickupTime >= 20 || pickupTime < 6) {
    cost += nightSurcharge;
}
```

This code right here adds `nightSurcharge` to the cost if `pickupTime` is greater than or equal to 20, OR less than 6. So of course it's added if it's less than 6.

```
if (pickupTime >= 20) {
    cost += nightSurcharge;
}
```

Now it will only add to it if it's greater or equal to 20.

Answer (score 0):

your code is:

```
if (pickupTime >= 20 || pickupTime < 6)
```

so if pickupTime is less then 6 it'll enter the if as well

http://jsfiddle.net/7rdzC/